# I am trying to randomize images on an HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

OK I am taking an introductory HTML class. This is my final project and I my have bitten off more then I can chew. **This is only for a class. No one else has to deal with the code it so it just needs to work. It will not be used or read by other developers.**

I am trying to make 20 different images randomly display 65 different pictures. The 20 images are divided between squares and rectangles. So there are 65 images that are squares and 65 images that are rectangles. They must randomly display in the 20 images in mu HTML body.

Here is the JavaScript code in my header:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 random.m=714025; random.a=4096; random.c=150889;
 random.seed = (new Date()).getTime()%random.m;
 function random()
 {
 random.seed = (random.seed*random.a + random.c) % random.m;
 return random.seed / random.m;
 }

 function randomizeimages()
 {
 randomizeimage('image1', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image2', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image3', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image4', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image5', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');

 randomizeimage('image6', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image7', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image8', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image9', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image10', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');

 randomizeimage('image11', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image12', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image13', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image14', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image15', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');

 randomizeimage('image16', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image17', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image18', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image19', 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
 randomizeimage('image20', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg'); 
 }

 function randomizeimage(img, count, base, type)
 {
 document.images[img].src = base + Math.floor(random() * count + 1) + type
 }
 </script>
```

Here is the portion of code dealing with images in the body of my HTML. I will only list the first 5 of 20 for the sake of space.

```
<div id="shape1">
<img name="image1" src="squares/2.jpg" alt="Square 1" width="162" height="162" />
</div>

 <div id="shape2">
<img name="image2" src="squares/3.jpg" alt="Square 2" width="162" height="162"   />
</div>

 <div id="shape3">
<img name="image3" src="rectangles/2.jpg" alt="Rectangle 1" width="324" height="162"   />
</div>

 <div id="shape4">
<img name="image4" src="squares/4.jpg" alt="Square 3" width="162" height="162"   />
</div>

 <div id="shape5">
<img name="image5" src="rectangles/3.jpg" alt="Rectangle 2" width="324" height="162"   />
</div>
```

Ect. for 15 more images making a total of 20. When I view the page in a web browser it simply lists the alt image name like it can't find the image. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "It will not be used or read by other developers." Except me.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't give one of my variables *and* one of my functions the same name (`random`).

Also, select your element with `document.getElementById()`. I gave your `<img>`'s some id attributes to help with that.

Updated HTML:

```
<div id="shape1">
    <img id="image1" src="squares/2.jpg" alt="Square 1" width="162" height="162" />
</div>

<div id="shape2">
    <img id="image2" src="squares/3.jpg" alt="Square 2" width="162" height="162"   />
</div>
```

Updated JS:

```
var random = {
    m: 714025,
    a: 4096,
    c: 150889
};
random.seed = (new Date()).getTime() % random.m;

function generateRandom() {
    random.seed = (random.seed * random.a + random.c) % random.m;
    return random.seed / random.m;
}

function randomizeimage(img, count, base, type) {
    var element = document.getElementById(img);
    element.src = base + Math.floor(generateRandom() * count + 1) + type;
}

randomizeimage('image1', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
randomizeimage('image2', 65, 'squares/', '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
document.images[img].src = base + Math.floor(random() * count + 1) + type
```

Specifically when you do images[img] you're trying to access an image by it's name, which doesn't work. images is an array, and you need to access that array by its index.

So you could do

```
function randomizeimage(index, count, base, type)
{
    document.images[index].src = base + Math.floor(random() * count + 1) + type
}
```

And change your calling code to this

```
randomizeimage(0, 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
randomizeimage(1, 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
randomizeimage(2, 65, 'rectangles/', '.jpg');
```

etc